# How do i handle the message Error: unexpected symbol in R?

Tags: r, error-handling

I have to design three research questions using the [dataset brfss2013](https://d18ky98rnyall9.cloudfront.net/_e34476fda339107329fc316d1f98e042_brfss_codebook.html?Expires=1537401600&Signature=VEr9IfkiRFEyQ74P2k6eXik~FD7dgAIDC3XgkbF0nGT2CfqLCmOFutxoCKmNO4w32fF4i~H-cMy1QTI9k2wkzb5FV-BiIzK3IUREYPLV7qp2rgOB6EF5aYm4KXi6EIhSjMjQGv6QwDLcCZlan6reX5OQNAmYO27a8d7GAVaHWM8_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A##avedrnk2).  The second one I am doing is *Do people who drink and smoke some days have higher blood pressure than people who don't at all?* To view the data before visualizing it, I tried to create a subset narrowing down to people who smoke two or three times a week.

```
smokers <- subset(brfss2013, smokday2 == 2 | smokday2 == 3, select = c(smokday2, avedrnk2))
```

I ran the code above and got the following error:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "smokday2 == 2 or"**

I tried eliminating the "|" symbol and the second piece of the subset argument making it:

```
smokers <- subset(brfss2013, smokday2 == 2, select = c(smokday2, avedrnk2))
```

But then got a table with zero rows.  Also, the data frame is very slow and out of sync in Rstudio so I can't examine brfss2013 very easily.  It's also huge.

Does anyone know what the issue is here?

Please let me know

Comment: What about smokday %in% c(2,3)?

Comment: Your example code doesn't match the error message, in the code you have `|` which should be correct but in the error message you have `or`. Are you sure you get the same error when rerunning with `|`?

Comment: "unexpected symbol" is *always* a syntax error.

Comment: I did rerun with | ! I also thought that may have been the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Funny story, I found the answer.  When I ran and didn't get a syntax error, I got a table with 0 rows.  I found out that the [data background/overview](https://d18ky98rnyall9.cloudfront.net/_e34476fda339107329fc316d1f98e042_brfss_codebook.html?Expires=1537401600&Signature=VEr9IfkiRFEyQ74P2k6eXik~FD7dgAIDC3XgkbF0nGT2CfqLCmOFutxoCKmNO4w32fF4i~H-cMy1QTI9k2wkzb5FV-BiIzK3IUREYPLV7qp2rgOB6EF5aYm4KXi6EIhSjMjQGv6QwDLcCZlan6reX5OQNAmYO27a8d7GAVaHWM8_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A##avedrnk2) claims smokday2 has values such as "2" or "3", but when running brfss2013$smokday2 I found that it actually is populated with strings of text such as "Some days", "Not at all", and "Every day".  Here is an example of the code I used for a functional subset:

somesmokendrink <- subset(brfss2013, smokday2 == "Some days" & avedrnk2 == c(2:4), select = c(smokday2, avedrnk2))